# Ender 3 with a battery powered backup

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, power-electronics, ups, solar-charge-controller

I wish to develop a battery powered power supply to provide uninterrupted power supply for long duration 3D prints in an environment where mains power is unreliable.

A regular ups power supply would require batteries but with 2 times power conversion from DC-AC (at the UPS) to AC-DC (at the printer power supply). So instead why not develop a 24 V power backup?
Ender 3 uses a 24 volt power supply to power the motherboard. Its power consumption varies from 120-245 W. Power supply is rated 360 W.

I am considering using [this](https://robu.in/product/30a-intelligent-lcd-solar-controller/) solar power controller to charge batteries (2 car batteries 35 Ah) with the ender 3 power supply connected in place of solar panel. The load being the printer motherboard. I am mostly going to use a capacitor at the motherboard to manage the drop in voltage when it switches from power supply to battery. We have many power cuts here, so going for this frugal way out. Several comments indicate that operation directly from bttery without some form of controller is not likely to be satisfactory.

Any and every suggestion is welcome.
I am yet to purchase the batteries (bit costly).
I have the solar controller with me doing some basic trials with a 12 V setup. With a 12 V LED strip as load and a 12 V battery and a 12 V 1 A power adaptor as the charger. I don't have a good battery, the one I have is unable to maintain 11.5 V. Usually the controller disconnects the load at 11.5 V.

Comment: Car batteries? not a good idea, try deepcycle or leisure batteries.

Comment: Have you investigated commercially made 24V ups systems?  Good chance there are several types available. The fact that you want to use a better battery wouldn't seem overly unique either. Little sense in reinventing the wheel each time.

Comment: Add a DC/DC (buck/boost) converter to your battery setup to maintain a fixed voltage independent of the voltage of your batteries. You can then either go for a 24 V battery setup or a 12 V setup with an appropriate charger, using only off-the-shelf components.

Comment: @StarCat That would be good as an answer.

Comment: Closwed. Edited. Reopened. This is a design question but not as obvious as it could be. Veers somewhat towards shopping BUT design definitely needed and helpful to others with similar needs.

Answer (score 0):

The challange you have is that a charging battery is 28V or sometimes even more.
Increasing the power of the heaters by 15% in the 3D printer, and also the torque of the motors.

What I would recommend is a decent battery charger with a DC-DC converter, such as Victro Orion-Tr 24/12-30 to maintain a stable 24V just as the PSU does now.

For sizing the battery charger you need more than the average power a printer draws when printing. You can allow the peaks, such as the preheating cycle to take a some energy from the battery, this is usually a short time.

Another solution would be get a Victron multiplus charger/inverters unit or similar. It works like a UPS, it is used in industrial panels and campers a lot. The main advantage over a UPS is that you have *freedom of battery*.
In normal mode there is a bypass relay and you do not lose power to dual conversion.
The big advantage is that you can keep the printer in original, known good and safe condition.

The inverter efficiency is pretty good (95%) today if you buy from reputable brands. The reason a typical small UPS is not is because they're not intended to run for very long, only until the genset kicks in or the systems are in a safe state.